# Creating Migrate.exe at a specific location in Fluent Migrator

Tags: asp.net, database-migration, fluent-migrator

I'm using Fluent Migrator 1.6.2 in my .Net application.

For migrating up or migrating down the database, Migrate.exe needs to be executed by passing assembly file (the dll file of the database project in which the migration classes exist) from the command line.
And by default, Migrate.exe file gets created inside \packages\FluentMigrator.1.6.2\tools folder.

I want both these files (Migrate.exe and DbProject.dll) to be created inside the same folder.

Is there any configuration setting in fluent migrator by which I can control the location at which Migrate.exe file gets created and create it inside my DB project?

Answer (score 2):

No such configuration exists. You however, can set a specific folder in your solution, where you copy the Migrate.exe file and other needed files, then set the properties of your Migrations project, to build to said folder, resulting in binaries generation every time you build the application.

Recommendation here is to have the migrations in their stand alone project inside your solution.